# How can I set a margin in px, to a centered div which maintains its aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, margin, aspect-ratio

I've got this div, which has a fixed ratio and ajusts itself to both the screen width and height. How can I can add a margin using px instead of vh / vw, while keeping it centered and from overflowing?

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vw * 5 / 7);
  max-width: 140vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May this helps

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vw * 5 / 7);
  max-width: 140vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 45px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.inner-div{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="inner-div">
    <!-- your content-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried wrapping it like you have, but it sadly ignores any sort of padding or margin of the div its in, when scaling itsself. I'm thankful for your effort nonetheless!